# how to run a Visual Studio code on a Linux (Ubuntu) server

Tags: linux, visual-studio

### running native C++ code on Linux server

Hello, everyone

I have implemented an algorithm in native C++ using Visual Studio 2010, and it runs well on my local PC. Now I want to run the processing on another remote Linux server with more CPUs.

Ideal case, I would like to control the process from my local windows PC and run remotely using many CPUs on Linux. In a simplified situation, I would like to run the program directly on the server.

Could anyone give some recommendations how I can implement this?

Comment: what do you mean by "native c++ code"? "Visual Studio" does not *run* any code, it is a compiler (suite) that produces binaries that can run on W32...

Comment: By native c++ I meant I didn't use CLR.

Comment: ok; C++ does not care about the EOL character you are using - so it odesn't matter whether you use CRLF, CR or LF, any decent compiler will be able to compile these files

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to compile the code to produce a Linux binary. As Visual Studio doesn't run on linux, or produce such binaries, you'll have to use a linux compiler - such as GCC or LLVM - to do this.

Once that task is done you might have to make some changes to the code to make it compile without any Windows-specific calls in it. After that, just run the program.

To communicate between machines, you'll have to make the program talk across the network - this is not a Linux/windows problem as you could get 2 windows machines to work in the same way. Try writing another exe that can communicate with your program and run them both on the same machine to start with, then you can move your program to another networked machine and see if it still works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the directions. So if I want to run interactively between two machines (no matter windows or Linux), I can still develop with Visual Studio but try to avoid windows-specific libraries?